# SKAction playsoundfilenamed fails to load sound

Tags: swift, audio, sprite-kit, skaction

No matter what wav file I tried to play in an project, I keep getting the same error. The error states: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Resource namedfile.wav can not be loaded'

I cannot get any sound of any kind to load using SKAction.playSoundFilenamed. I have made sure that the file is names correctly and that doesn't seem to be the problem.

I have tested this in several projects, including the following test Game project wherein I use all default code except for a call to the SKAction

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
        myLabel.text = "Hello, World!";
        myLabel.fontSize = 65;
        myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
        let soundfile = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("soundProject.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
        runAction(soundfile)
        self.addChild(myLabel)
    }
```

I cannot get any sound of any kind to load using SKAction.playSoundFilenamed. I already checked to made sure that the file is named correctly and that it exits in the bundle. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

**UPDATE** I Ran my attached code on a different computer, and it compliled and ran perfectly. There must be something wrong with my xcode/simulator. Does anyone know how to reset it? Thanks

Comment: see https://github.com/sc24evr/TestAudioSpriteKit for a sample project that gives me the errors

Comment: Same problem for me. I work on a project for weeks and suddenly there are problems loading sounds. Cleaning or removing derived data does not solve it.

Comment: Restart computer solve the problem for me.

Comment: I had This issue on the simulator XCode 10.1 but on the device, the sound played. I restarted XCode and Simulator and it worked there also.

Answer (score 34):

When you select your sound file in XCode, access the inspector on the right side, then make sure the file is selected for your target(s).

[image: CaptureTarget]

Comment: I check the target as suggestioned and the correct project target was selected. I think Xcode knows that the file exists but is failing to load it. For example, if I intentionaly misspell the file name in he code, I get an error saying the file isn't found. Here rather I get an error saying the resource "can not be loaded".

Comment: Is the sound played only once or somewhere else ? Just to be sure it's crashing here. I'm trying to look is there is any restriction about the : sound time length, sound file size, sound bitrate, ... Can you give me those informations for you file ? Or even upload it so I can try to play it in my own app.

Comment: I've suggested an other lead in a second response. Please give a look at it and let me know if it helped. If it didn't, please give me more information about the file or upload it.

Comment: This solves my problem, thanks. When I drag `m4a` into project, the target is unmarked by default, but for `mp3` or `CAF` file the target is marked by default. Is it the normal behavior of Xcode?

Answer (score 9):

What color is your Sounds folder?

If it's blue, it means it's a **Folder Reference**.
If it's yellow, it's a **Group**.

You Choose Folder Reference -vs- Group when you import your folder.

I've found that **SKAction.playSoundFilenamed** functions correctly only when it's loaded as a **Group** (Yellow).

Comment: yes, for "blue" folder, You will have to build all path using:

`let myBundlePath  = Bundle.main.bundlePath
  let pathInBundle = myBundlePath+"/"+mediaFolder+"/"+name`

Comment: I found the same issue, blue folder will not work with `SKAction.playSound...`. We should use yellow one (Group) when dragging some resources folder into the project, though it is weird.

Answer (score 3):

For me, this was the issue. Both of these compiled fine and gave no errors, but only the latter actually played the sound.

Did not work:

```
SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("combo.mp3", waitForCompletion: true)
```

Did work:

```
node.run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("combo.mp3", waitForCompletion: true))
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another lead that might help you.

Sometimes SKAction is not very handy with audio files.
*I haven't found in which case exactly (might be : size file, sound length, ...).*

In that case, you would want to use `AVAudioPlayer`instead of it.

In order to not write your own "player", I suggest you to use an existing one. Here is one I've already used (SKTAudio) : https://github.com/raywenderlich/SKTUtils/blob/master/SKTUtils/SKTAudio.swift

Here is how to use it :

```
// For background audio (playing continuously)
SKTAudio.sharedInstance().playBackgroundMusic("music.wav") // Start the music
SKTAudio.sharedInstance().pauseBackgroundMusic() // Pause the music
SKTAudio.sharedInstance().resumeBackgroundMusic() // Resume the music

// For short sounds
SKTAudio.sharedInstance().playSoundEffect("sound.wav") // Play the sound once
```

Please let me know if the file is not played even with `AVAudioPlayer`. If so, it might be a problem with it and not the way it's played.

Comment: I tried that and still couldn't get the sound to play. I uploaded the project i made to test this at https://github.com/sc24evr/TestingSound1 . I still received an error sadly  "TestingSound1[28834:778122] 18:40:39.824 ERROR:     168: EXCEPTION thrown ('fmt?'):"

Comment: Here is the project that I try to use the SKAction where I keep getting errors. https://github.com/sc24evr/TestAudioSpriteKit

Answer (score 2):

for swift 3.0:

```
    SKAction.run {
      SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("soundProject.wav",
      waitForCompletion: false)
    }
```

and of course, verify if the resource is in project/copy Phases.

Answer (score -1):

I identified the issue. I had to change the sound settings on my mac through the system preferences. Once I changes all of the settings to use only the internal speakers, the problem was resolved.

Comment: Ya definitly a weird issue. Thanks again for all your suggestions. They helped me narrow down the problem significantly.

Answer (score -1):

swift 5:

Instead of

```swift
SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Sounds/theme.mp3",
                                                   waitForCompletion: true))
```

I wrote

```swift
SKNode().run(
    SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Sounds/theme.mp3",
                                                       waitForCompletion: true))
)
```

And it works good.